# Error - Firebase.push failed:

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to push a collection of questions and associated options to a firebase ref called 'quizzes'. When clicking submit I get the following in the console.

`Uncaught Error: Firebase.push failed: first argument  contains an invalid key ($$typeof) in property 'quizzes.questions.0'.  Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"`

I have no idea what `($$typeof)` means here or really how to solve this issue. I'm pushing Option components into a Question components array [ ] and then pushing the question component into the QuizBuilderForm array [ ].

Thanks!

Here is my code

```
// Quiz Builder Component

import React from 'react';
import Question from './Question';
import firebase from 'firebase';

const QuizBuilderForm = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            questions: [],
        };
    },
    addQuestion: function(questions, index) {
        index = this.state.questions.length;
        questions = this.state.questions;
        questions.push(<Question key={index} id={index}/>);
        index++;
        this.setState({
            questions: questions
        });
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.addQuestion();
    },
    handleSubmit: function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref('quizzes');
        this.firebaseRef.push({
            questions: this.state.questions
        });
        this.refs.form.reset();
        this.setState({
            questions: []
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <form className="quiz-form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} ref="form">
                {this.state.questions}
                <button type="button" className="add-question" onClick={this.addQuestion}>Add a question</button>
                <button type="submit">Create Quiz</button>
            </form>      
        );
    }
});

export default QuizBuilderForm;

// Question Component 

import React from 'react';
import Option from './Option';

const Question = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            value: "",
            options: []
        };
    },
    handleChange: function(e) {
        this.setState({
           value: e.target.value 
        });
    },
    addOption: function(options, index) {
        index = this.state.options.length;
        options = this.state.options;
        options.push(<Option key={index} id={index} />);
        index++;
        this.setState({
            options: options

        });
    },
    componentDidMount: function() {
        this.addOption();
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="question">
                <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                {this.state.options}
                <button type="button" onClick={this.addOption}>Add another option</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

export default Question;

// Options component 

import React from 'react';

const Option = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            value: ""
        };
    },
    handleChange: function(e) {
        this.setState({
            value: e.target.value
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <input type="text" value={this.state.value} placeholder="Enter an answer here" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>        
        );
    }
});

export default Option;
```

Comment: Try logging the contents of this.state.questions right before the push() event. You'll find that this is a React component, and contains special keys beginning with $ and $$. Those characters aren't allowed in Firebase keys, so it's being rejected, as the error indicates. You'll need to parse that data to be valid JSON and the keys to match Firebase's allowed schema--you won't be able to save a React object directly to the DB like you've attempted here.  Check out [reactfire](https://github.com/firebase/reactfire) for simpler integration.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess I'm not really sure how to go about parsing the data. I'm not very familiar. I think where I'm getting stuck is I'm dynamically adding input fields and I'm unsure of a good way to grab each dynamically added input fields value so I can add it to Firebase. Obviously this is a piece of cake with a static form, just grab the ref, but pretty challenging for me with a dynamic form. Any suggestions there? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 major mistakes that I find in your code.

1. You are trying to push a react component on firebase which is not going to work. You need to push an array of string or an array of objects.
2. You are trying to set the sub-component at the state variable of the parent component. You shouldn't be doing that. You need to set the data you want to display as the state of the component and then pass this data to your sub-component and let sub-component decide how to render it.

Comment: Ok. Number 1 makes sense. I guess I wasn't really expecting it to work I just am not sure how to convert my arrays to strings or objects. Do you have any recommendations on how to go about this?

Comment: The data you want to save should be the state variable of your parent component. In your case it should be like this.
var data = [{
   value : "",
   options:["", "", "", ""]
}];

This should generate 1 question with four options.
If you want to add a new question you need to do this.
this.state.data.push({
   value : "",
   options:["", "", "", ""]
});
You need to iterate over this array and send the data as props to child component and child component should display the data. 
Hope this gives you a direction. I will give you the code if this doesn't help.

Comment: Yeah that helps! ! I will try on my own and let you know how it goes. Thanks a lot.